# How to print an image from an url in a form in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is a tiny form, where I paste a valid URL, click the button and show the image in the third input type element:

```
<input id="url" type="text">
<br><input id="getImage" type="button" onclick="getImages()" value="Get the image!">
<br><br><input id="showImage" type="image">
```

And this is my javascript:

```
function getImages() {
    url=document.getElementById('url').value;
    imagen=document.getElementById(showImage).value='<img src="'+url+'">';
}
```

I´ve just have my first javascript class, and wanted to know what function to use, I understand that this `imagen=document.getElementById(showImage).value='<img src="'+url+'">';` is not correct.

I get this error when I try to run the script:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Naturally, the offending line is:

```
imagen=document.getElementById(showImage).value='<img src="'+url+'">';
```

I would like to learn what function could print that out. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct function.
You forgot to use '
And you should close that inputs tags.

```
function getImages() {
    url=document.getElementById('url').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('showImage').innerHTML='<img src="'+url+'" />';
}
```

Maybe a better code would be:

```
<input id="url" type="text" onChange="getimages();"></input>
<br><br><div id='showImage'></div>
<script>function getimages() {
    url=document.getElementById('url').value;
    document.getElementById('showImage').innerHTML='<img src="'+url+'" />';
}</script>
```

So instantly when you paste the link the image should appear.

Answer (score 1):

FORM element have values. HTML elements have innerHTML.

```
document.getElementById('showImage').innerHTML='<img src="'+url+'">';
window.print();
```